# get field names in a Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i have a django model with several DateField. the model is:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    aaa = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="x")
    nnn = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="y")
    ddd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="z")
    ...
```

i want to compare all dates from my model and use it in a template. am able to do that using in my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
    aaa = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="x")
    nnn = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="y")
    ddd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="z")
    ...
    def timing(self):
      fields = (
        self.aaa, self.nnn, self.ddd, ...
      )
      past = []
      for field in fields:
        if field:
            if field >= datetime.now().date():
                past.append( [True, field] )
            else:
                past.append( [False, field] )
        else:
            pass
      return past
```

in template:

```
{% for bl, value in c.timing %}
    {% if bl == False %}
      <dt>{{ bl }} :</dt> <dd>{{ value }}<dd>
    {% else %}
      <dt>{{ bl }} :</dt> <dd class="c1">{{ value }}<dd>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

that works but i want to have the verbose name of fields in my template. so i can use for exemple

```
    {% if bl == False %}
      <dt>{{ fielname }} :</dt> <dd>{{ value }}</dd>
```

thanks for all answers in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can define a name for the field, with a default name and not editable, something like this:

```
aaa_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='aaa_name', editable=False)
```

Then to access it in the template you can just call it like usual:

```
{{ aaa_name }}
```